# Reduce/reduce conflict in grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, yacc

Let's imagine I want to be able to parse values like this (each line is a separate example):

```
x
(x)
((((x))))
x = x
(((x))) = x
(x) = ((x))
```

I've written this YACC grammar:

```
%%
Line: Binding | Expr
Binding: Pattern '=' Expr
Expr: Id | '(' Expr ')'
Pattern: Id | '(' Pattern ')'
Id: 'x'
```

But I get a reduce/reduce conflict:

```
$ bison example.y
example.y: warning: 1 reduce/reduce conflict [-Wconflicts-rr]
```

Any hint as to how to solve it? I am using GNU bison 3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is not `LR(k)` for any `k`. So you either need to fix the grammar or use a [`GLR` parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/GLR-Parsers.html).

Suppose the input starts with:

```
(((((((((((((x
```

Up to here, there is no problem, because every character has been shifted onto the parser stack.

But now what? At the next step, `x` must be reduced and the lookahead is `)`. If there is an `=` somewhere in the future, `x` is a `Pattern`. Otherwise, it is an `Expr`.

You can fix the grammar by:

- getting rid of `Pattern` and changing `Binding` to `Expr | Expr '=' Expr;`
- getting rid of all the definitions of `Expr` and replacing them with `Expr: Pattern`

The second alternative is probably better in the long run, because it is likely that in the full grammar which you are imagining (or developing), `Pattern` is a subset of `Expr`, rather than being identical to `Expr`. Factoring `Expr` into a unit production for `Pattern` and the non-Pattern alternatives will allow you to parse the grammar with an `LALR(1)` parser (if the rest of the grammar conforms).

Or you can use a GLR grammar, as noted above.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. In the real grammar patterns and expressions are similar but not identical (they generate different nodes in the AST). Enabling the GLR parser in bison indeed solves the problem (I guess the performance won't be as good, but I don't really care if this simplifies the grammar).

Answer (score 2):

Reduce/reduce conflicts often mean there is a fundamental problem in the grammar.

The first step in resolving is to get the output file (`bison -v example.y` produces `example.output`).  Bison 2.3 says (in part):

```
state 7

    4 Expr: Id .
    6 Pattern: Id .

    '='       reduce using rule 6 (Pattern)
    ')'       reduce using rule 4 (Expr)
    ')'       [reduce using rule 6 (Pattern)]
    $default  reduce using rule 4 (Expr)
```

The conflict is clear; after the grammar reads an `x` (and reduces that to an `Id`) and a `)`, it doesn't know whether to reduce the expression as an `Expr` or as a `Pattern`.  That presents a problem.

I think you should rewrite the grammar without one of `Expr` and `Pattern`:

```
%%
Line: Binding | Expr
Binding: Expr '=' Expr
Expr: Id | '(' Expr ')'
Id: 'x'
```

Comment: Thanks! that indeed solves the conflict, but I should have noted in the question that patterns and expressions in the real grammar are similar but not identical.